# Declaring a scope property

Tags: angularjs

I'm just learning angulerjs.

I’ve seen examples that have code similar to the following in an AngularJS controller:

```
$scope.menuState.show = false;
```

However, that doesn’t work. The following does:

$scope.menuState  = [show: false];

Show the previous line work? Just wondering since I've seen it in an Angularjs reference book.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you actually mean

```
$scope.menuState = {show: false}; // create an object with one 'show' field = false
```

which is equivalent to

```
$scope.menuState = {}; // create an empty object
$scope.menuState.show = false; // add a field 'show' with value false
```

So, the example you saw probably created the object (or had one already via prototypal inheritance) before the line adding the show field.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You are correct, the book excluded the empty object creation.